# Outlook OLE Automation: BodyFormat not supported?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am trying to send an email in Outlook using OLE Automation. At the moment, I am using VBS for testing purposes. When it works, I will switch to another language that supports OLE/COM.

The problem with my code is, that I get error **800a0005 "Invalid procedure call" with argument 'BodyFormat'.**

According to the [documentation of Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/aa211430), `BodyFormat` is existing since Outlook 2003. I am testing with Outlook 2010.

My code:

```
Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")

Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With newMail
       .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
       .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"
       .Display
End With
```

The background: At the moment, some customers receive emails in TNEF format and can't open the email attachment **winmail.dat**. So I am trying to force Outlook to use HTML instead of RichText.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant `olFormatHTML` is not defined by default.

Add the following line at the beginning of your `VBS` code:

```
Const olFormatHTML = 2
```